# Best approach for caching lists of objects in memcache

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, memcached

Our Google AppEngine Java app involves caching recent users that have requested information from the server.

The current working solution is that we store the users information in a list, which is then cached.

When we need a recent user we simply grab one from this list.

The list of recent users is not vital to our app working, and if it's dropped from the cache it's simply rebuilt as users continue to request from the server.

What I want to know is: Can I do this a better way?

With the current approach there is only a certain amount of users we can store before the list gets to large for memcache (we are currently limiting the list to 1000 and dropping the oldest when we insert new). Also, the list is going to need updating very quickly which involves retrieving the full list from memcache just to add a single user.

Having each user stored in cache separately would be beneficial to us as we require the recent user to expire after 30 minutes. At the moment this is a manual task we do to make sure the list does not include expired users.

What is the best approach for this scenario? If it's storing the users separately in cache, what's the best approach to keeping track of the user so we can retrieve it?

Comment: The user information is very basic, currently not even entities. The list is a simple list of hashmaps, where one hashmap represents one user. The hashmap contains the users gender, language, insertion timestamp and the users iOS push notification identifier is it exists.

Comment: HashMap sounds like the wrong data type. HashMap is effective only for a large number of key-value pairs. I would simply store a "user" entity in memcache.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep in the memcache list just "pointers" that you can use to build individual memcache keys to access user entities separately stored in memcache. This makes the list's memcache size footprint a lot smaller and easy to deal with.

If the user entities have parents then pointers would have to be their keys, which are unique so they can be used as memcache keys as well (well, their urlsafe versions if needed).

But if the user entities don't have parents (i.e. they're root entities in their entity groups) then you can use their datastore key IDs as pointers - typically shorter than the keys. Better yet, if the IDs are numerical IDs you can even store them as numbers, not as strings. The IDs are unique for those entities, but they might not be unique enough to serve as memcache keys, you may need to add a prefix/suffix to make the respective memcache keys unique (to your app).

When you need a user entity data you 1st obtain the "pointer" from the list, build the user entity memcache key and retrieve the entity with that key.

This, of course, assumes you do have reasons to keep that list in place. If the list itself is not mandatory all you need is just the recipe to obtain the (unique) memcache keys for each of your entities.

Comment: Thanks. Having pointers in the list instead of the entity (or hashmap in my case) is a good idea, but the only benefit for me is that I will be able to store more in the list. My individual cached users would expire after 30 minutes, leaving pointers in the list to objects which do not exist..

Comment: Hence my last paragraph: do you actually need a list or the list is just an artifact of the existing caching solution? Do you need to know which exactly are the users that requested info from the app in the past 30 min (which may explain the list) or you just want to be able to use (up to 30 min old) cached user info instead of the datastore info (which you can do without a list)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [NDB caching](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache), it will take care of memcache for you.  Simply request the users with the key using [ndb.Key(Model, id).get()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_get) or [Model.get_by_id(id)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_by_id), where id is the User id.